# Spring can't find class from shared Gradle library (dependency in autowired bean) when debugging in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

## Problem Definition

I have a Spring MVC project which is Gradle-based. I have a website project (`zeario-web`), web crawler (`zeario-webcrawler`), and shared classes (`zeario-sharedclientserverclasses`). The web and web crawler share some classes (something like DTOs or VOs).

In my web app, I have a `CrawlerController` with a `getWorkUnit` method; this calls a method on a `CrawlerService` instance (`@Autowired` depdency), which, in turn, uses some classes from the shared library.

My problem is that **I can build and deploy a working version of my web app via Gradle, but not via Eclipse.** Eclipse gives me a spring runtime exception about not finding one of the shared classes, and being therefore unable to create/inject the service instance.

From the Tomcat logs:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crawlerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.zeario.service.CrawlerService com.zeario.api.v1.controller.CrawlerController.service; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zeario/api/v1/model/workunit/PageDiscoveryWorkUnit

## Code Snippets

Controller definition (simplified):

```
@Controller
public class CrawlerController {


    @Autowired
    private CrawlerService service;

    // ... methods with @RequestMapping ...
}
```

Service class (simplified):

```
@Service
public class CrawlerService {

    public PageDiscoveryWorkUnit getPageDiscoveryWorkUnit() {
        return new PageDiscoveryWorkUnit();
    }
```

`PageDiscoveryWorkUnit` is a simple POJO/Bean class. I have my service beans declared in the `spring-servlet.xml` file:

```
<bean id="crawlerService" class="com.zeario.service.CrawlerService" />
```

## Gradle Configuration

1) Root project (empty, no source) defines sub-projects in `settings.gradle`. Dependencies are in `build.gradle`:

```
project(':zeario-web') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':zeario-sharedclientserver')
    }
}

project(':zeario-webcrawler') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':zeario-sharedclientserver')
    }
}
```

2) Projects define dependencies on other projects where applicable. For example, the web project build file contains:

```
dependencies {
    // Guava, Spring MVC, etc. ...
    packed project(':zeario-sharedclientserver') // Shared code
    // ...
}
```

## Eclipse Configuration

When I check build paths, Eclipse correctly shows project dependencies; for example, it shows that the `web` project has a dependency on the `shared client/server` project.

Comment: So are you using Eclipse itself to build? Or running Gradle *through* Eclipse rather than the command line?

Comment: @Vidya I am using Eclipse itself to build. Gradle build infrastructure is only there to manage dependencies and support building a JAR to deploy to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Vidya who helped me realize that the issue is *Eclipse*, not *Gradle*. The problem is that Eclipse failed to copy the files into the JAR that it built.

Steps to fix this problem:

- Right-click the Web project and pick `Properties`
- Click on `Deployment Assembly` and click `Add`
- Select `Project`, and pick the shared library
- Clean, rebuild, and deploy

Et viola, problem solved!

Note: Eclipse sometimes has a brain fart, and requires you to remove and re-add the project dependency. I ran into this, too.

Comment: Congratulations on finding the issue. I think community rules call for an upvote for my answer and an accept (and an upvote too) for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Eclipse is not packaging the jar that contains `PageDiscoveryWorkUnit` into the war. This gets to how you configured Eclipse. Confirm this by unpacking the wars produced both ways and comparing the contents of `*WEB-INF/lib*. Then tinker with your Eclipse configuration to make sure the jar gets added.

Comment: This is good insight, but doesn't really help me. If Eclipse already sees the dependent project as a dependency, it's not obvious why it's not copying over the JAR or class files.